# Yahoo Finance Python API JSON error?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I have been trying to use the Yahoo Finance Python API to get historical prices but I every time I try to run my code, I get the same error. Here is my code and the error:

The Python Code

```
from yahoo_finance import Share 

name = Share('YHOO') 
temp = (name.get_historical('2014-04-25','2015-04-29'))

print (temp)
```

And the Error Message

```
> 
> JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-1-65dd835a5e8b> in <module>()
> ----> 1 from fetch import *
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/SMP/fetch.py in <module>()
>       3 
> ----> 4 name = Share('YHOO')
>       5 temp = (name.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2015-04-29'))
>       6 
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.py
> in __init__(self, symbol)
>     176         self._table = 'quotes'
>     177         self._key = 'symbol'
> --> 178         self.refresh()
>     179 
>     180     def _fetch(self):
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.py
> in refresh(self)
>     140 
>     141         """
> --> 142         self.data_set = self._fetch()
>     143 
>     144 
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.py
> in _fetch(self)
>     179 
>     180     def _fetch(self):
> --> 181         data = super(Share, self)._fetch()
>     182         if data['LastTradeDate'] and data['LastTradeTime']:
>     183             data[u'LastTradeDateTimeUTC'] = edt_to_utc('{0} {1}'.format(data['LastTradeDate'], data['LastTradeTime']))
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.py
> in _fetch(self)
>     132     def _fetch(self):
>     133         query = self._prepare_query(table=self._table, key=self._key)
> --> 134         data = self._request(query)
>     135         return data
>     136 
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.py
> in _request(self, query)
>     116 
>     117     def _request(self, query):
> --> 118         response = yql.YQLQuery().execute(query)
>     119         try:
>     120             _, results = response['query']['results'].popitem()
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.2.1-py3.5.egg/yahoo_finance/yql.py
> in execute(self, yql, token)
>      58 
>      59     self.connection.request('GET', PUBLIC_API_URL + '?' + urlencode({ 'q': yql, 'format': 'json', 'env': DATATABLES_URL }))
> ---> 60     return simplejson.loads(self.connection.getresponse().read())
>      61 
>      62   def __del__(self):
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py
> in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int,
> parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, use_decimal, **kw)
>     514             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None
>     515             and not use_decimal and not kw):
> --> 516         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     517     if cls is None:
>     518         cls = JSONDecoder
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py
> in decode(self, s, _w, _PY3)
>     368         if _PY3 and isinstance(s, binary_type):
>     369             s = s.decode(self.encoding)
> --> 370         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
>     371         end = _w(s, end).end()
>     372         if end != len(s):
> 
> /Users/peterbullard/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py
> in raw_decode(self, s, idx, _w, _PY3)
>     398             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
>     399                 idx += 3
> --> 400         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
> 
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If it helps, I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.

This is the console log from terminal.

> W 08:59:40.681 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version,
>   assuming version 1 [I 08:59:41.410 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels]
>   enabled, 2 kernels found [I 08:59:41.459 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is
>   already in use, trying another port. [I 08:59:41.765 NotebookApp]
>   [nb_anacondacloud] enabled [I 08:59:41.768 NotebookApp] [nb_conda]
>   enabled [I 08:59:41.821 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
>   [W 08:59:41.821 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No
>   module named 'nbbrowserpdf' [I 08:59:41.825 NotebookApp] Serving
>   notebooks from local directory: /Users/peterbullard [I 08:59:41.825
>   NotebookApp] 0 active kernels  [I 08:59:41.825 NotebookApp] The
>   Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/ [I 08:59:41.825
>   NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all
>   kernels (twice to skip confirmation). [I 08:59:53.346 NotebookApp]
>   Kernel started: 92b75861-94a5-4002-9ab4-97988c0cebfe [W 08:59:53.365
>   NotebookApp] 404 GET /kernelspecs/Python%20[Root]/logo-64x64.png (::1)
>   11.76ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/SMP/Test.ipynb [I 08:59:55.917 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted:
>   92b75861-94a5-4002-9ab4-97988c0cebfe

Comment: I just installed this module using PIP (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4) and I don't see this issue. And I'm using Python 3 as well. Sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the instructions from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

It says:

> Yahoo! Finance backend is http://datatables.org/. If this service is down or has network problems you will receive errors from group YQL*, eg. YQLQueryError.

So the service is out and that's why you keep getting a YQL error. I'm assuming the service hasn't been on for a while now if this was an issue back in 2016.

For a fix you can try the Yahoo Query Language (YQL). Here is the page to get started there https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/#python